# Java how Scanner works

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I would like to figure out how class Scanner works. For example, we have the line:"74 89", I call method nextInt() and how Scanner separates to integers? Or why it throws InputMismatchException if we pass the line "74;89" to nextInt() - the difference only between the splitting symbol?

Comment: Have you tried to read the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Scanner.java.html)? It's not very difficult. You're more likely to get a good answer if you ask specific questions about the source.

Comment: The docs are specific enough, and easier to understand than the source; an answer from the docs is usually better than an answer from the source, unless the question is about implementation details or is so specific that the docs don't cover it.

Answer (score 0):

"The Java Scanner class breaks the input into tokens using a delimiter which is whitespace by default. It provides many methods to read and parse various primitive values." - https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class

So in your example:

- `74 89` `nextInt()` will read `74` as the next integer because it is
  separated from the next token by a whitspace.
- `74;89` `nextInt()`will not read any integer from this as there is no whitespace to separate the tokens (integers) from each other.